# Ayuda! (Entity Framework. C#) El tipo de entidad Publicacion no forma parte del modelo del contexto actual

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET y Entity Framework (Base First). Agregué dos tablas nuevas, actualizando el modelo de base de datos desde el explorador de modelos, como siempre hago. Pero cuando quiero obtener la entidad Publicacion me sale el siguiente error:

El tipo de entidad Publicacion no forma parte del modelo del contexto actual.

¿Cómo puede ser? revisé el explorador de modelos y la clase Publicacion se encuentra en mi proyecto, como todas las demás. Les paso captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Stacktrace

> en
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
> entityType)    en
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
> entityType)    en
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    en System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()    en
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() en System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
> en System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
> source)

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy bien formulada, pero podrias como referenciar mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]?  gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya revisaste si cuentas con un archivo .edmx? En caso de contar con el, revisa las entidades que contiene. En caso de que si cuentes con el y también tengas la entidad.

Comment: Revisé el archivo .edmx y tengo la entidad Publicacion. No comprendo el por qué del problema todavía